# Defining a new math relation

Tags: mathtools

In group theory, a `$p$`-normally embedded subgroup `$H$` of a group `$G$` is denoted by `$H$ $p$-ne $G$`. I want to define a new command for `$p$-ne` to work within the math environment but I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\pne}{\mathrel{p\mkern1mu\textrm{-ne}}}

\begin{document}

    \[ H \pne G\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used initially `\mathrm`, but the hyphen is then a  minus sign, which obviously is unwanted. But you're right, L'll update the answer. Thanks for pointing the problem!